# Why do significance levels in the Shapiro test for normality fluctuate with the number of observations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

When simulating the Shapiro test for normal distributed data in R I encountered that the p-values for rejecting the Null-Hypothesis often increase in the range of ~30 to ~200 observations, than decrease again and than somehow fluctuate. How can I explain this behavior? Intuitively I thought that with a larger number of observations, the p-values would increase as well and that I would get low p-values especially if I have a small number of observations.

```r
test <- vector(length = length(10:5000))
for(i in 10:5000){
  set.seed(500)
  test[i] <- shapiro.test(rnorm(i))[[2]]}
plot(test)
```

[image]

If you change the seed the results look different, however the general pattern is often similar.

Comment: This isn't telling you anything useful about the Shapiro test or anything else. 
 *Remove* the seed setting.  If you don't, you induce extremely strong relationships among successive results and all you get is a variation of a random walk.

Comment: If I remove the seed setting than there is no pattern at all any more with p-values between 0-1 for any level of observations... shouldn't be the general pattern an increase in robustness and hence higher p-values? Is this a specific problem of the `rnorm` function?

Comment: No, the p-value is *defined* in such a way that when it is correctly and accurately calculated, when the distribution of the test statistic is continuous, and the null hypothesis holds, it will be randomly and uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$.  All of those circumstances apply to your experiment.

Answer (score 4):

This question is resolved by applying software engineering principles.

---

The plot is a very roundabout and computationally expensive way to construct a random walk.

To see what this means, let's redo the code to make it faster and clearer:

```R
set.seed(500)
x <- rnorm(5000)
test <- c(rep(0, 9), sapply(10:5000, \(n) shapiro.test(x[1:n])$p.value))
```

You can plot `test` to verify the results are identical.  *Notice that the data vector `x` never changes.*  The `sapply` function loops over the indices $n = 10, 11, \ldots, 5000$ and applies the function `shapiro.test` to the first $n$ entries in the *constant* vector `x`.

*The same qualitative behavior arises with most other functions.*  Consider this variant where `shapiro.test` is replaced by a t test:

```R
test <- c(rep(0, 9), sapply(10:5000, \(n) t.test(x[1:n])$p.value))
plot(test, type = "l")
```

When applied to the very same vector `x`, the plot is qualitatively like that in the question:

[image]

Abstractly, let $f$ represent the function `shapiro.test` or `t.test` or whatever.  Its values are p-values in the range $[0,1].$  The plot maps each $n$ to $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n).$

This abstract description helps clarify how the points on the plot evolve from left to right: $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is followed by an updated version $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}),$ *where $x_{n+1}$ is a random value independent of the first $n$ values in $x.$*

Let's express this conventionally.  The vector `x` is the computer's realization of the mathematical sequence $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n,\ldots$ of independent random variables (all with standard Normal distributions in this example).  The sequence being plotted is

$$S = f(X_1), f(X_1,X_2), \ldots, f(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n), \ldots$$

*It generalizes the archetypical random walk where $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n.$*  Unless $f$ doesn't depend at all on $x_1,\ldots, x_n,$ the updated value must be related to the previous value: successive points on the plot are not independent.  That's what makes the plot wander around rather than producing a bunch of scattered points.

---

The intention behind this code might have been to study what happens to the *distributions* of the Shapiro-Wilk p-values as they might depend on the sample size.  If so, *the code is erroneous.*

A good approach to implementing the intention is to *encapsulate* the problem by putting the data generation and testing into a function.  Below, the function `simulate` generates `n.sim` samples of size `n` using a common random number generator `distribution`, applies the function $f$ (passed as `statistic`), and returns `n` p-values.  By wrapping all this in a call to `sapply` it allows the caller to pass a vector of various sample sizes in `n`, returning an array whose columns correspond to those sample sizes. All this can be done in one line.

```R
simulate <- function(n, statistic, distribution, n.sim = 5000, ...) 
  sapply(n, \(n) apply(matrix(distribution(n * n.sim, ...), n), 2, statistic))
```

(The ellipsis `...` permits the caller to pass named arguments to `distribution` to vary its parameters if desired.)

Let's use this function to study the Shapiro-Wilk p-values for *iid* Normal samples (the null distribution).  This one uses sample sizes of $10,$ $20,$ $50,$ and $100.$  Because the main computation was encapsulated, this requires only one line, making it easy to verify the correctness of the implementation (subject to verifying that `simulate` works as intended).

```R
n <- c(10, 20, 50, 100) # Sample sizes
set.seed(17)
Sim <- simulate(n, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value, rnorm)
```

Here is what plots of the columns look like.

```R
for (i in seq_along(n)) 
  plot(Sim[, i], col = "#00000020", ylab = "p value", main = bquote(n==.(n[i])))
```

[image]

*The p-values are (literally) all over the place,* exactly as one would hope when the data are generated from the null distribution for the test.

Maybe it's better to examine histograms of these p-values, now that we have seen there's no sequential pattern to them.

```R
for (i in seq_along(n)) {
  hist(Sim[, i], freq = FALSE, xlim = 0:1, xlab = "p value", main = bquote(n==.(n[i])))
```

[image]

They look just like samples of a uniform distribution.  Everything works as it should, *regardless of the sample size.*

**The extreme abstraction of `simulate` pays off here.**  By making one tiny change we can study how well the Shapiro-Wilk test performs *under a specific alternative hypothesis.*  Consider, for instance, what happens when the data are drawn from a Gamma$(5)$ distribution:

```R
Sim <- simulate(n, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value, rgamma, shape = 5)
```

The p-value distributions now look like these:

[image]

As the sample size grows, a small p-value becomes more and more likely.  *The test grows more powerful with increasing sample size.*